# Copying individual subfolders between Subversion branches

Tags: svn

We have a trunk and a branch (call it branch1) in our Subversion repo. branch1 was created off of trunk. A new project was added to a subfolder in branch1 (call it branch1\source\newproject). Other changes were made to branch1 also. Now I want to copy newproject (and only newproject) from branch1 to trunk. What's the best way to do that?

The naive answer is to simply make a copy of newproject in the trunk location (trunk\source\newproject), from the branch1 location. But I'm unclear if there problems with doing that. Specifically, I want to be able to periodically merge changes from branch1\source\newproject to trunk\source\newproject. I'm unclear if the naive copy will make the merging difficult or impossible. Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Copying and then merging later as you describe will work fine. As far as svn is concerned, copying a folder is the same thing as creating a branch, so subsequent merge operations will work just as they do for branches.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `svn merge` command. [1](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re16.html)

Comment: You should really elaborate a bit on the subject instead of just posting a link. Would improve this answer heaps. (just saying as it came up in the "low quality post" review, not my -1)